# Как получать данные в kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

я не могу понять, почему за пределами okHttp клиента ответ не подхватывается, а внутри, там где Test2 все ок... Вроде в java так можно.

```
var srtUri: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(URL).build()
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val json = response.body?.string()
            srtUri = (JSONObject(json).get("url")).toString()
            Log.d("Test2", "Test2: $srtUri")
        }

    })

    Log.d("Test1", "Test1: $srtUri")

}
```

[image: Как получать данные в kotlin]

Comment: а где вывод Тест2?

Comment: @Эникейщик в onResponse. test2 выводит strUri. Но за пределами okHttp не хочет.

Comment: я не совсем об этом. Приложение запускается, в какой момент выводится Тест2? Сразу после запуска или что-то еще перед этим происходит?

Comment: @Эникейщик Сразу

Comment: до или после тест1?